# How do I start the Secret Armory of General Knoxx in Borderlands on XBOX 360

Tags: borderlands, borderlands-secret-armory-of-knoxx

I have Borderlands on the XBOX 360. I purchased and downloaded the Secret Armory DLC. There's no T-Bone Junction fast-travel point that is supposed to exist in the game with any existing characters, do I need to start over and play through the game again to make it appear?

UPDATE: re-downloading the DLC worked.

Comment: Thats a very good question..... I have always been able to get there from "day 1" with any character, but i have GotY, so i always had them.... if you do make a new character, it should be there right away (you dont have to repair the Fast Travel Network) once you get into Fyrestone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Access T-Bone Junction from the Fast Travel points.** It shows for all characters after the install—there's no need to play through the game again to make it appear. (I installed the DLC after I finished the original game.) If you're having trouble, install all latest patches, reinstall the DLC, and reset your cache and try it all again (in this order).

[image: Fast Travel]

Comment: 'install latest patches' sounds like something you might do with the PC version, not XBOX 360. Any outstanding updates will be applied if you start the game while connected to XBOX Live. 'reinstall the DLC' also sounds PC oriented. There _is_ an option to re-download the DLC, which I am testing. I'm not sure what 'reset the cache' means, either.

Comment: I belive by "reset the cache" he means deleate the xbox cache, and so "reset" the games cache

Comment: @postfuturist reset the game cache just deletes all updates for your xbox